# "required gtk+ version 3.10, current version is 2.24" - Glade+Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, ubuntu-14.04, glade

I want to use Glade Interface Designer with Python 2.7, but when I try to run my code I get the following error:

```
:required gtk+ version 3.10, current version is 2.24
```

I have the gtk+ 3.10 installed, but I don't know how to change the path to use the 3.10 version.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Did you remember to install the development files?

Comment: What is your import statement for GTK+?

Comment: @andlabs I've tried **import gtk**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using PyGTK, which is only for GTK+ 2. Switch to python-gobject, which allows using GTK+ 3. Coding with it seems to be very similar to coding with PyGTK, so migrating your code shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Do you mind to explain how to do it? Or, could you indicate some reference? @andlabs

Comment: I don't know; sorry.

Answer (score 2):

`import gtk` is for GTK2 with pyGTK.
If you want to code in python for GTK3, you'll need:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

Read [The Python GTK+ 3 Tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).